# Py4JJavaError: Job aborted due to stage failure from Spark on Windows

Tags: python, windows, apache-spark, pyspark, py4j

I've built the latest spark from git (`branch-1.4`), however I get an error when doing file IO:

```
if not locals().get('sc'):
    try:
        import findspark
        findspark.init()
    except ImportError:
        pass

    import pyspark
    sc = pyspark.SparkContext(appName="myAppName")

fileName = 'pg100.txt' # from http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/100/pg100.txt
print '\n'.join(sc.textFile(fileName, 8).take(5))
```

#### Error

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:109)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:153)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
    at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(BufferedOutputStream.java:126)
    at java.io.DataOutputStream.write(DataOutputStream.java:107)
    at java.io.FilterOutputStream.write(FilterOutputStream.java:97)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeUTF(PythonRDD.scala:600)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.org$apache$spark$api$python$PythonRDD$$write$1(PythonRDD.scala:415)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$$anonfun$writeIteratorToStream$1.apply(PythonRDD.scala:425)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.writeIteratorToStream(PythonRDD.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread$$anonfun$run$3.apply(PythonRDD.scala:248)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1772)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$WriterThread.run(PythonRDD.scala:208)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

BTW: All normal stuff with `parallelize` work fine.